# Updates are not working

Tags: 12.04, updates

Updates in my system are not getting installed..

`sudo apt-get install` is giving the following error:-

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cdh4 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 327574EE02A818DD
```

Update Manager is showing different error as shown in ScreenShot
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and add the missing key with below command

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 327574EE02A818DD
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```